# App is not Working when I use a Nested Component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using a Nested Component for Star Rating in my App, but when i add it, it does not work in my app. I have used the selector of my new component in my template, and have declared in app.module declarations as a component.

star.component.html

```
<div class="crop" 
[style.width.px]="starWidth"
[title]="rating">
<div style="width: 86px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

star.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'ai-star',
templateUrl: 'app/shared/star.component.html',
styleUrls: ['app/shared/star.component.css']
})

export class StarComponent implements OnChanges {
rating: number=4;
starWidth: number;

ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.starWidth = this.rating * 86 / 5;                            
}

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.Component';

import { ProductFilterPipe } from './products/product-filter.pipe';
import { StarComponent } from './shared/star.component';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
declarations: [    AppComponent,ProductListComponent,ProductFilterPipe,StarComponent],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I use only one Module(Root) for all my components. If i have missed anything please help to resolve this.

Comment: are you getting any error ? if possible provide plunker for the same

Comment: plz show your routing.ts file. i think you are doing mistake there..

Answer (score 0):

you are not importing your routing file in your @NgModule
your routing file should be like this.

```
import {
    Route
} from '@angular/router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {
    CsvTimelineComponent
} from './modules/core/csvtimeline/csvtimeline.component';
import {
    CsvJsonComponent
} from './modules/core/csvjsonparse/csvjson.component';
import {
    CsvAddCategoryComponent
} from './modules/core/addcategory/addcategory.component';
import {
    LoginComponent
} from './modules/loginComponent/login.component';
import {
    TemplateComponent
} from './modules/core/template.component';
import {
    DashboardComponent
} from './modules/core/dashboard/dashboard';

export const routes: Route[] = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "login",
    pathMatch: "full"
}, 
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
}, 
{
    path: 'csvtemplate',
    component: TemplateComponent,
    canActivate: ['canActivateForLoggedIn'],
    children: [{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard'
    }, 
    {
        path:'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'csvtimeline/:month/:year',
        component: CsvTimelineComponent,
        canActivate: ['canActivateForLoggedIn'],
    }, {
        path: 'csvjson',
        component: CsvJsonComponent
    }, {
        path: 'addcategory',
        component: CsvAddCategoryComponent
    }
    ]
}];
```

and in your module.ts file should be like this

```
import {
    NgModule
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    BrowserModule
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
    RouterModule
} from '@angular/router';
import {
    AppComponent
} from './app.component';
import {
    routes
} from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),<-- you are missing this 
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [  ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: OP is asking about nested components not routing.

Comment: then he should include more code. only then we can can tell where is the problem. Its not clear from this code what he is trying to do

Comment: what I am trying to do is add 5 star ratings to my product ratings from a Nested Component(star.component.ts). I use only one module and I don't use a separate routing file to import. As I use this in root component.. Can you specify any files so I could display them. thanks.